# I accidentally sent uni token to contract address. Can i get it back?

Tags: erc-20

Instead of transferring my Uni token to my binance wallet, tokens dropped to contract address.
I tried to send my 400 uni tokens to my wallet in binance with the metamask wallet. but as you can see the tokenes have gone to the contract address.
i try to contact to uni creators many times but they have not back to me.

The link below takes you to the etherscan contract with my Uni token sitting in the address.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x041f0ab37f90397dc6427eb202d0b78f27f5652baa6cdd33c849ce1d4c32c3b6
how can i get back tokens?

Comment: Unfortunately that contract doesn't provide any way to recover tokens transferred to it.

Comment: I have the same issue. Wrongly sent some petrons to Etherem wallet on my coinbase account, I wanted to send them to my Ethereum Wallet on Metamask.